# Fano manifold admit an smooth anti-canonical divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ ba a compact Kaehler Fano manifold. Under which conditions $M$ admit a smooth anti-canonical divisor $D$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $M$ is *smooth* and $\dim M =3$, then the answer is *always*. This is a theorem due to Shokurov, see

V.V. Shokurov: [*Smoothness of a general anticanonical divisor on a Fano variety*](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.ed.ac.uk%2Fcheltsov%2Fshokurov%2Fpdf%2Felephant.pdf&ei=f0LKVOPtF9fvaO65gYgC&usg=AFQjCNFPX_liED_da0wBLoycMKGuf04Amg&bvm=bv.84607526,d.d2s),  Math.
USSR, Izv **14**, 395-405 (1980).

In fact, Shokurov proves the following more precise result.

> **Theorem.** Let $M$ be a smooth Fano threefold of index $r$ and let $H \in \textrm{Pic}(M)$ such that $rH \cong -K_M$. Then the general element of the linear system $|H|$ is smooth.

Using a terminology due (I think) to M. Reid, smooth anticanonical divisors in Fano threefolds are sometimes called *elephants*.

Answer (score 6):

In general there may not be smooth anticanonical divisors. Of course if you take divisors in the linear system $|-mK_X|$ for $\gg 1$ there will be lots of smooth divisors, by Bertini's theorem (precisely when $|-mK_X|$ is basepoint free). But if you restrict to $m=1$ this is not always the case.

For an example of a Fano manifold without a smooth anticanonical divisor, see the work of Taro Sano: http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0705 Example 2.9. Apparently the first such examples are due to Hoering-Voisin: http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2853 Example 2.12.