# Calabi-Yau theorem on arithmetic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, calabi-yau

Let $\mathcal X\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal O_K)=C$ be an arithmetric projective variety over $C$ , where $\mathcal O_K$, ring of number filed $K$. Let $\omega$ be a Kähler current of $\mathcal X(\mathbb C)$. Assume that the arithmetic first Chern class $c_1(\mathcal X)$ vanishes.

> Then what can we say about $\mathrm{Ric}(\omega)$? Is there any Calabi-Yau
>   like theorem?

Have we such formula $$c_1(\mathcal X(\mathbb C))=[\mathrm{Ric}(\omega)]$$

In fact arithmetic first Chern class is in Chow group and '$\mathrm{Ric}$' is in $H^2$ and they have different cohomology.

> More generally, If the anti-canonical arithmetic line bundle is
>   negative, then can we say $\mathrm{Ric}(\omega)=-\omega$ ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is a forgetful functor from arithmetic cohomology to singular cohomology that respects Chern classes. E.g., if you represent $c_1(\mathcal X)$ by a divisor of the canonical bundle, you would obtain the Poincaré dual of that divisor. Assuming that $\mathcal X(\mathbb C)$ is smooth, the answer would then be "yes" by the classical Calabi-Yau theorem, because (as far as I know), arithmetic geometry does not impose any further constraint on the Kähler form.

Comment: you mean http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195180/fano-manifold-admit-an-smooth-anti-canonical-divisor ?

Comment: I don't see the connection. You don't need specific properties properties of the divisor, just that it gives $0$ in cohomology. But you already assumed $c_1(\mathcal X)=0$ even in the arithmetic setting.

Comment: I have used "Kahler current" and not Kahler form

Comment: Please specify the kind of Calabi-Yau theorem you hope for. I thought you mean $\mathrm{Ric}=0$ on all of $\mathcal X(\mathbb C)$. This means, forget the Kähler current and find a Ricci-flat Kähler form in the specified Kähler class. If $\mathcal X(\mathbb C)$ is smooth, I don't see an obstacle. Or do you simply ask for the displayed formula, which does not look like a Calabi-Yau theorem to me?

Comment: In Kahler current setting which is the singular version of Kahler form we have still Ricci flat Kahler current. In fact We can define first Chern class In the sense of current cohomology. We can say $Ric(\omega)=0$ In current sense